# I can't find my funds on my bitcoin wallet

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions, funds

I can't find my funds on my blockchain wallet after saving for over 1 years. My blockchain account show (00) total when i have saved 3 BTC what should i do ? please help

Answer (score 1):

> what should i do

It depends whether you have a Blockchain.com account or a Blockchain.com wallet.

If you have a Blockchain.com account, contact Blockchain.com support.

If you have a Blockchain.com wallet, check the transaction history and find the Bitcoin addresses which held your money. You can then check those addresses in several different  [blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer) to see if money has been removed from those addresses. If not you may be able to regain control by  re-creating your wallet from your recovery phrase or wallet backups.